# How do I get this property by using Power Shell?

Tags: powershell, properties, explorer

**The details of my problem:**

I have some `.m4a` recording files. I can use the `Explorer` to get detail from `Properties > Details > Origin > Media created`. But as you may know, the `Properties` window does not show time in `HH:MM:SS` format but only in `HH:MM`, and I do need the `second` very much.

I learned a way to fetch info by `Power Shell` code something like this:

```
(Get-Item C:\Users\natsu\Desktop\FolderName\RecordingFile.m4a).VersionInfo | select Media created
```

But, `select Media created` returns an error, `select "Media created"` returns blank value. I can avoid the `space` in the path but I don't know how to `escape` it in the command.

May you please help me: (1) Try telling me the correct command for the `Power Shell`. or (2) Other Applications that can read it in `HH:MM:SS` format?

This may look so silly and simple for you but please consider that I am not a professional user. Sorry for my bad English. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

**What did I try:**

I did try `sttmedia` but this application does not support the `Media created` property.

I did try `Explorer++` but this application can only show in `HH:MM` format too.

**What am I expecting:**

I want to get my `.m4a` files, for the `Media created` property, in `HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: You don't have to re-invent the wheel again. Simply use what others already shared with the world. Here you have a function `Get-FileMetaData` extracting meta data information: [GETTING FILE METADATA WITH POWERSHELL SIMILAR TO WHAT WINDOWS EXPLORER PROVIDES](https://evotec.xyz/getting-file-metadata-with-powershell-similar-to-what-windows-explorer-provides/)

Comment: Since I don't have a test file to play around with I assumed it would show it when this porperty is actually populated. Do you have a source where I could download a test file?

Comment: @Olaf As an example, `Get-FileMetaData` returns `DateModifies: 2022/03/01_14:21` and `MeidaCreated: _2022/_01/_18___00:10`.

Comment: So you will have to wait until I get an iPhone.  ... I understood the you actually don't see the info when you look it up in Windows Explorer, right? Maybe the information is actually not there.  ‍♂️

Comment: @mklement0 I thought the `18` still belongs to the date - not the time.  ‍♂️ The test file I found online does not have seconds.

Comment: Ah, good point, @Olaf - I misread that. I'll delete my previous comment and just repost the ExifTool tip.

Comment: A general tip (it may or may not help with the specific problem): [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is a powerful CLI for extracting and updating metadata embedded in image and video files. On Windows, you can install it with `winget install OliverBetz.ExifTool`. Example call that extracts the creation-date timestamp from an image file in JSON format: `exiftool -j -CreateDate IMG_5522.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

**Get-FileMetaData** uses the object/function **$ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf()** to retrieve the information which returns string values.
That's why it's not getting the 'seconds' information you need.

You can use the **ExtendedProperty** of the **$ShellFile object** which will return a DateTime object instead.

The **Media Created** corresponds to the **DateEncoded** property. You can either use its 'Attribute Path/Name' or 'Format Identifier/Property ID' pair.
Information can be found here: [Property System Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-media-dateencoded)

Here is a code example (note that the value returned is in UTC format):

```
$Targetfile  = "C:\Temp\SAMPLE.m4a" ;

$FileInfo    = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Targetfile ;
$ShellApp    = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application ;
$ShellFolder = $ShellApp.Namespace($FileInfo.Directory.FullName) ;
$ShellFile   = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FileInfo.Name) ;

# Get Attribute Value and Check the Type of Data returned:
Write-Host 'Using $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty with Attribute Name (data in UTC format)' -ForegroundColor Green ;
$Value = $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty("System.Media.DateEncoded") ;
Write-Host " Media Created: $($Value)`n Property Type: $($Value.GetType().FullName)" ;
Write-Host ;

Write-Host 'Using $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty with FMTID/ID (data in UTC format)' -ForegroundColor Green ;
$Value = $ShellFile.ExtendedProperty("{2E4B640D-5019-46D8-8881-55414CC5CAA0} 100") ;
Write-Host " Media Created: $($Value)`n Property Type: $($Value.GetType().FullName)" ;
Write-Host ;
```

You can add this code to compare the data returned by the function **ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf()**:

```
# In comparison to the $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf()
Write-Host 'Using $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf function (data in GMT+X format)' -ForegroundColor Green ;
$Value = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, 208) ;
Write-Host " Media Created: $($Value)`n Property Type: $($Value.GetType().FullName)" ;
Write-Host ;
```